# Получение текущего времени в переменную

Tags: android, время

Пишу приложение для часов, и мне требуется получить текущий час и минуты в `int hour` и `int min`

Как это правильно реализовать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); //часы 0-24
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR); //часы 0-11
int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Comment: ``calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)`` дает просто час. AM/PM там нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик, имел ввиду, что подразумевается am/pm. Исправил, чтобы не путать

Comment: Если требуется АМ/ПМ (ну мало ли), то для этого можно ``calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM)`` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#AM_PM)

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int hours = Integer.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(calendar.getTime()));
int minutes = Integer.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(calendar.getTime()));
textView.setText("Hours: " + hours + " Minutes:" + minutes);
```

Comment: Зачем же придумывать свой велосипед, если уже есть готовый метод.